# Mistake in calculation $|c_l|^2\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta \sin(\theta)(\sin(\theta))^{2l}=1$

Tags: definite-integrals, factorial, gamma-function, quantum-mechanics

I did probably a mistake in calculation but I cannot find it.
I start from 
$$|c_l|^2\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta \sin(\theta)(\sin(\theta))^{2l}=1$$
$$I_{l}=\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta \sin(\theta)(\sin(\theta))^{2l}=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(l+1)}{\Gamma(l+\frac{3}{2})}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi} \,\,l!}{(l+\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(l+\frac{1}{2})}$$
replacing:
$$\frac{2\pi|c_l|^2\sqrt{\pi} \, l!}{(l+\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(l+\frac{1}{2})}=1$$
$$|c_l|=\frac{1}{2^l \, l!}\sqrt{\frac{(l+\frac{1}{2})(2l)!}{2\pi}}$$
but the correct result is:
$$\boxed{|c_l|=\frac{1}{2^l \, l!}\sqrt{\frac{(2l+1)!}{4\pi}}}$$

Someone can tell me where I was wrong and show me how to get the correct result.

Comment: its seems to me both a,nswers are the same multiply numerator and denominator by 2 ...enter the ewpression inside the factorial

Answer (score 1):

Both results are the same answer...

$$|c_l|=\frac{1}{2^l \, l!}\sqrt{\frac{(2l+1)!}{4\pi}}=\frac{1}{2^l \, l!}\sqrt{\frac{(2l)!(2l+1)}{4\pi}}=\frac{1}{2^l \, l!}\sqrt{\frac{(2l)!(l+1/2)}{2\pi}}$$